# How can I create a BufferedReader from a String?

Tags: java

I am trying to pass a String to my `BufferedReader`. How can I pass "test" as `String` to the reader rather than the input from `System.in` ?

```
String test = "test";
BufferedReader inFromUser = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));
```

Answer (score 50, accepted):

You can modify your code as below

```
String test = "test";
Reader inputString = new StringReader(test);
BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(inputString);
```

Answer (score 11):

No point in buffering a string. Just

```
String aString = ...;
Reader inFromUser = new StringReader(aString);
```

Comment: but how to send it to the server in this way. Can u please adapter your answer to my code to understand your solution?

Comment: String message = "#2016011400#";
  Socket clientSocket = new Socket("localhost", 39537);
  DataOutputStream outToServer = new DataOutputStream(clientSocket.getOutputStream());
  outToServer.writeBytes(message + '\n');
  clientSocket.close();. I have tried the following but it does not work for me.

Comment: To make sure it's actually sent to server, call `outToServer.flush()` after `writeBytes` (and read the result before closing the socket).

Comment: there *is* a point in buffering a String if it's huge and you want to read it line-by-line

Comment: @JonathanLandrum If you have a String, it's already fully in memory by definition. If you just mean that `BufferedReader` has the `lines()` method, and `StringReader` doesn't, fair enough, but it's fixed in Java 11 (https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/String.html#lines()).

Comment: @AlexeyRomanov correct, it is fully in memory, but an expensive process is easier to call on a subset of a huge string rather than the whole thing at once. I didn't know about the changes in Java 11, we're still stuck on 1.8! >_<

Comment: A point might be: unit testing a method which expects a `BufferedReader`, and providing it as a `String` is the easiest.